# How to draw figures in three dimensions in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

185/5000
I already work with TIKZ in two dimensions, but I never needed to do anything related to three dimensions, I would like to know if anyone can help me to start this drawing below.[image]

Comment: You could look at the `3d` library described in [TikZ documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or at the [`tikz-3dplot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) package to get started.

Answer (score 5):

Using Tikz in 3D is pretty much the same as it is in 2D - except you have to use 3D coordinates instead of 2D.

Here's how you can draw a 3D box (as you can see, you can mix 2D and 3D coordinates. In that case the z-coordinate of the 2D representations is automatically assumed to be zero):

```
\beging{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(8,0) -- ++(0,-4) -- ++(-8,0) -- ++(0,4) -- ++(0,0,-4) -- ++(8,0) -- ++(0,-4) -- ++(0,0,4) ++(0,4,0) -- ++(0,0,-4);
    \draw[dashed] (0,-4) -- ++(0,0,-4) -- ++(8,0,0) ++(-8,0) -- ++(0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And here's a slightly more involved example (electromagnetic wave):

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-10:1cm)},y={(90:1cm)},z={(210:1cm)}]
    % Axes
    \draw[->] (-1,0,0) node[above] {$x$} -- (5,0,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[left] {$z$};
    % Waves
    \draw[red,thick] plot[domain=0:4.5,samples=200] (\x,{cos(deg(pi*\x))},0);
    \draw[blue,thick] plot[domain=0:4.5,samples=200] (\x,0,{cos(deg(pi*\x))});
    % Arrows
    \foreach \x in {0.1,0.3,...,4.4} {
      \draw[red] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,{cos(deg(pi*\x))},0);
      \draw[blue] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,0,{cos(deg(pi*\x))});
    }
    % Labels
    \node[red, above right] at (0,1,0) {$\vec{\bm{E}}$};
    \node[below, blue] at (0,0,1) {$\vec{\bm{H}}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

This yields
[image: EM wave]